# ASLR in Linux Vs Windows

Tags: disassembly, windows, linux, stack

I am quite new in binary exploitation. I am doing a lot of beginners exercise here. I am confused about ASLR. I tried some binary exploitation thing in Linux. It was recommended that I should stop ASLR in Linux before analyzing the binary.
it is the command for that --> `echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space`
Am I right here? am I turning off my ASLR (randomizing stack addresses)?

But When I did the Windows 10 binary exploitation(vulnserver). I had to put my payload into stack address. And I noticed that the stack address (`jmp esp`) was constant, not changing.
Is ASLR works differently in various OS?
I don't know If I am asking a write question. please tell me if you know.

Comment: Did you check if the binary has /DYNAMICBASE property set? If it is not set then it means that REBASE was opted out while compiling the program itself i.e. ASLR is not being used.

Comment: how do I check it in windows?

Answer (score 3):

By using [this tool](https://blog.didierstevens.com/2010/10/17/setdllcharacteristics/) from Didier Stevens you've been able to check/set/unset DEP/ASLR characteristics of your file.
Check the file like this:

```
setdllcharacteristics.exe yourfile.exe
```

If the output said `DYNAMIC_BASE    = 0` then you can use `+d` option to enable `DYNAMICBASE` of your file:

```
setdllcharacteristics.exe +d yourfile.exe
```

And you can use `-d` to unset again.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, the command `echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space` disables ASLR. From [here](https://www.networkworld.com/article/3331199/what-does-aslr-do-for-linux.html):

> The value shown will be one of the following:
>
> 0 = Disabled
>
> 1 = Conservative Randomization
>
> 2 = Full Randomization

2. There are several differences in the implementation of ASLR between Windows and Linux, you can search for them online, but to your question: In Windows, an EXE or a DLL can be compiled with or without ASLR (same goes for DEP - Data Execution Prevention).
   For the purpose of exploitation, we search for code without protection (you can find it with WinDBG using [mona modules](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/metasploit-revealed-secrets/9781788624596/9b9ac2e7-127a-4f3b-80c6-7e9b8149573f.xhtml) or [narly](https://github.com/d0c-s4vage/narly/blob/master/narly/ReadMe.txt), for example), in order to try to jump to it and run a code of our choice.
   Therefore, what you have probably seen is a jump to such a code without ASLR, and it's fine that the address is fixed (no ASLR!). If you have control over the stack, the `jmp esp` command jumps to the stack, and there you can put whatever code you want.